# Прилагательное «подневольный» с дополнением

Tags: лексика

Может ли прилагательное "подневольный" вступать в отношения управления с дополнением?

> Он подневолен своему хозяину.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос давнишний и, как мне кажется, интересный.
[Подневольный](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — зависимый, подчиненный (нам подходит это значение прилагательного).
Честно скажу, что ориентировалась только на примеры использования, потому что ни в словарях, ни в справочниках каких-либо объяснений не обнаружила.

Вот что нашлось в Нацкорпусе:
**1.** *«Метрополь» не обливал грязью власть и **подневольную ей** страну. ...самым поразительным был тот факт, что в социалистической, братской, но **подневольной нам** Польше фильм Вайды все-таки вышел на экраны* (Владимир Молчанов, Консуэло Сегура. И дольше века...).
**2.** *Мертвецы, **подневольные моей памяти**, склоняются над постелью* (Сергей Шаргунов. Ура!).
**3.** *Вот другое такое же лицо в Питере, сутенер, на русской земле за 30 тысяч долларов в демократической России отпускает на волю и продает **подневольную ему** проститутку, русскую красавицу из Мурманска, полюбившему ее человеку* (Валерий Петров. Путин как Анна Иоанновна (2003) // «Завтра», 18.02.2003).
**4.** *Если же неверующий супруг уходит, пусть уходит, брат или сестра **им не подневольны*** (Библия. Современный русский перевод... Первое письмо христианам в Коринфе).

В других источниках:
**1.** ***Ферзям**, звучащим в диссонанс,

Король отнюдь **не подневолен**.

Ругнувшись, будто в первый раз,

Себя наглец в цугцванг загонит.*
Борис Зыков. Пикакокинг

**2.** *Я сумасшествием не болен,

Мой разум рифмою живет.

Мой ум **свободе подневолен**,

Для рабства он не подойдет.*
Владимир Проскуров. Откровение

**3.** *Ни с кем не дружит рок. Ты **року подневолен**.

Он даже не вздохнет, терзает — и доволен,

А если и вздохнет, так только для того,

Чтоб погасить свечу у тех, кто обездолен.*
[Авторство не смогла определить.]

**4.** *Глава Белоруссии умело шантажирует, но он не учитывает, что Киев **подневолен Вашингтону*** (из статьи).
**5.** *Компания «АвтоВАЗ» же **подневольна группе** Renault из Франции и породнится с ее «дочкой» Dacia* (из статьи).

Предполагаю, что дательный падеж (кому/чему) в этих сочетаниях вполне уместен. Во всяком случае, не коробит. (Обозначила свою точку зрения. Жду клевков.)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, и только нет. Оно здесь употребляется подобно причастию. Структура:
*Он что сделан своему хозяину.*
Причина такого восприятия: приставки (а их тут две) являются, по Розенталю, одним из признаков причастия.

Если использовать полную форму, то это станет очевидно:
*Он подневольный своему хозяину.*
Это всё равно что:
*Он добр своему хозяину.*

На то и существуют причастия, чтоб использоваться с зависимыми словами.

Правильно так:
*Он подневолен/подневольный (качество) для своего хозяина.*

Comment: Попытайтесь, пожалуйста, в своём ответе заменить "подневолен" на "неподвластен" (и прилагательные тоже). Это поможет оценить силу Ваших аргументов.

Comment: С некоторыми словами употребляется дательный падеж: (*нужен мне, неподвластен мне*), но далеко не со всеми. С ними звучит и полная форма. Но не *подневольный мне*, так люди не говорят. Не пойму: вам нужны аргументы получше или вы считаете иначе? Старайтесь это указывать.

Comment: *Он подневолен для своего хозяина* — Вы слышали, чтобы люди так говорили или писали? Ответ на Ваш вопрос: я могу согласиться только с первыми тремя буквами Вашего ответа. Все остальные буквы безнадёжно испортили этот ответ (таково моё мнение, раз уж Вы его спрсили).

Comment: "Вы слышали, чтобы люди так говорили или писали" — это да, но зато корректное согласование. Мысль была в этом. **Какими аргументами вы бы оперировали?** Тут и выбрать-то особо не из чего. Нет у меня ничего другого. Лучше хоть что-то, чем пустой ответ.

Comment: Нет, не лучше. Лучше честно объяснить, что зачастую управление в русском языке объясняется сложившимися традициями, а не какими-то аргументами или правилами. Попытки придумать несуществующие аргументы могут только запутать и в конечном итоге навредить автору вопроса (да и Вам тоже, я считаю).

Comment: Традиции и звучание — вещи субъективные, аргументы не ахти. Например, кто-то часто слышал слово "кроссовка", а кто-то нет. Где-то есть традиция так говорить, а где-то это дико.